# Why if $R_M \subseteq R_L $ then $Index(R_L) \leq Index(R_M)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, formal-languages

i was reading a proof in a book .
There are equivalence relations $R_M$ and $R_L$. The proof showed $R_M \subseteq R_L$ at the end it said because of this we can follow that $Index(R_L) \leq Index(R_M)$.

This is not intuitive to me. Could someone please help me understand. $Index(R)$ is the number of equivalence classes in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $R_M\subseteq R_L$ means that whenever $x\mathrel{R_M}y$, then $x\mathrel{R_L}y$.

Suppose that $A$ is an equivalence class with respect to $R_L$; if $x\in A$, then its equivalence class with respect to $R_M$ is contained in $A$.

Therefore each $R_L$-equivalence class is the union of $R_M$-equivalence classes.

Comment: You mean $x R_L y$ in that first sentence ?

Comment: @asddf Yes, sorry: copy, paste and forget to change the symbol. :-)

Comment: Sorry but im not understanding it well yet. Why is the last sentence true ?

Comment: @asddf Collection of typos, now it should be OK

Comment: Its making sense now, thank you :)